# Lambda expression in CreateHostBuilder in Web API project

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have started learning C# and Web API recently. When I created a new ASP .NET Core Web Application in Visual Studio 2019, it generated some code for WeatherForecast. Following is code segment that I am having trouble understanding.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
}
```

What is operator => doing here? CreateHostBuilder is a static method of class Program. And its definition should start with { and end with }. But after the closing braces of argument list, operator => is placed. I don't understand how this syntax works. Appreciate help in understanding this.
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the first arrow operator in this Func<T, TReturn> mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58597957/what-does-the-first-arrow-operator-in-this-funct-treturn-mean)

Comment: I also gave an example in an answer. But yes, probably a duplicate of the above mentioned comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called `expression-bodied`.

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        });
```

It's the same as:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
{
    return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        });
}
```

Just a shortcut to a body with return. You can also use it for void functions with 1 line (and no return). Especially useful with properties:

```
private string name;
// new way:
public string Name { get => name; set => name = value; }
// old way:
public string Name { get { return name; } set { name = value; }
```

You can read more about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members